# android wear emulator doesn't run and gets stuck

Tags: android

Hello I have an android wear emulator for API 21 with system-image Armeabi-v7a.
when i want to run it, it gets stuck on the stage which 4 circles move around.
I have waited for 3 hours but it is still stuck.
And I can't use Intel x86 because my CPU doesn't support that at all.
What should I do for that?

Answer (score 0):

emulator always works too slow , so use your android phone to run your project with USB debugging on

Comment: it's an android wear. i don't have an android wear device